# cross join returning date duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I applied a `cross join` to get a desired number of rows (4 rows per `computer` and `chip`). This works fine but when I introduce a date column, my cross join query blows up.

Before introducing the `date` column:

```
select t1.computer,t1.chip,transactions from generate_series (1,4) as transactions cross join 
(
select distinct computer,chip from the_table
)t1
order by 1,3

computer            chip            transactions
dell               intel                 1
dell               intel                 2
dell               intel                 3
dell               intel                 4
lenovo             samsung               1
lenovo             samsung               2
lenovo             samsung               3
lenovo             samsung               4
```

- Good up to this part!

When I add a `date` column, the query blows up, more or less results in duplicates:

```
select t1.computer,t1.chip,t1.date_purchased,transactions from generate_series (1,4) as transactions cross join 
(
select distinct computer,chip,date_purchased from the_table
)t1
order by 1,3,4

computer            chip          date_purchased             transactions
dell               intel              5/11/21                     1
dell               intel              5/11/21                     2
dell               intel              5/11/21                     3
dell               intel              5/11/21                     4
dell               intel              5/12/21                     1
dell               intel              5/12/21                     2
dell               intel              5/12/21                     3
dell               intel              5/12/21                     4
dell               intel              5/13/21                     1
dell               intel              5/13/21                     2
dell               intel              5/13/21                     3
dell               intel              5/13/21                     4
lenovo             samsung            5/17/21                     1
lenovo             samsung            5/17/21                     2
lenovo             samsung            5/17/21                     3
lenovo             samsung            5/17/21                     4
lenovo             samsung            5/18/21                     1
lenovo             samsung            5/18/21                     2
lenovo             samsung            5/18/21                     3
lenovo             samsung            5/18/21                     4
```

What I am attempting to get:

```
computer            chip          date_purchased             transactions
dell               intel              5/11/21                     1
dell               intel              5/12/21                     2
dell               intel              5/13/21                     3
dell               intel               null                       4
lenovo             samsung            5/17/21                     1
lenovo             samsung            5/18/21                     2
lenovo             samsung             null                       3
lenovo             samsung             null                       4
```

If the data is unavailable for a `date` for the listed transactions then return null for the `date_purchased`.

Is there anyway to get my intended result!

Comment: What does your data look like?  Where are the `NULL` values coming from?  What is the logic for your desired results?

Comment: @ Gordon, if the data has yet to come in for a date then have a `null` for the column. Once the data comes in for a date, it would populate replacing the `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I speculate that you want four rows per computer/chip combinations with different dates, if they are available.  If so:

```
select computer, chip, tt.date_purchased, transactions
from generate_series (1, 4) gs(transactions) cross join 
     (select distinct computer, chip
      from the_table
     ) cc left join
     (select tt.*,
             row_number() over (partition by computer, chip order by date_purchased desc) as transactions
      from the_table tt
     ) tt
     using (computer, chip, transactions)
order by 1, 3, 4
```